# batch file for .png?

Tags: batch-file

quick question. Have a batch file that will generate a .txt file when a .png is place into the directory. Will it be possible to include the date the .png was created next to the line with a "".

For example:

```
.png "9/14/2010"  
.png "9/14/2010"  
.png "9/14/2010"
```

right now I have this as my batch file: 
`dir /B *.png > name.txt`

which shows this

```
.png     
.png  
.png
```

Comment: You cannot have `"` in filenames, assuming you're in Windows.  I can't comment on *nix since I have never tried there before :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off
echo. > name.txt
for %%i in (*.png) do echo %%i "%%~ti" >> name.txt
```